# How do you put a table in a table in clj-pdf?

Tags: clojure, clj-pdf

I'm trying to make a pdf in Clojure with a one-to-many structure.
Something like:

```
+------+----+------+-------+------+
| Name | ID | Make | Model | Year |
+------+----+------+-------+------+
| Bob    23 | Volvo   240    1980 |
|           | Saab     99    1985 |
+-----------+---------------------+
| Foo    32 | Opel    XXX    1972 |
```

And so on.
The way I've tried is to do like this

```
(pdf/pdf [
    {:orientation :landscape}
    [:table {:header ["Name" "ID" "Make" "Model" "Year"]}
        [[:table {:colspan 2} ["Bob" "23"]]
         [:table {:colspan 3} ["Volvo" "240" "1980"]
                              ["Saab" "99" "1985"]]]
        [[:table {:colspan 2} ["F00" "32"]]
         [:table {:colspan 3} ["Opel" "XXX" "1972"]]]]
    ]
    "foo.pdf")
```

This is one of the versions that I've tried (and every permutation I could think of). Needless to say, it hasn't worked at all!

Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Regards

Comment: You might look into a library or service that turns html into pdf.  Docraptor is a service that charges money for pdf generation, but we have had good luck with them.  https://docraptor.com/

Comment: Have you tried `[(clojure.string/join " " ["Bob" "23"])]` ?

Comment: Or directly `["Bob 23"]` if this is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:cell`

Cells can be optionally used inside tables to provide specific style for table elements, including `:colspan`.

This is untested :

`[:table {:header ["Name" "ID" "Make" "Model" "Year"]}
        [[:cell {:colspan 2} [:table ["Bob" "23"]]]
         [:cell {:colspan 3} [:table ["Volvo" "240" "1980"]
                              ["Saab" "99" "1985"]]]]
        [[:cell {:colspan 2} [:table ["F00" "32"]]]
         [:cell {:colspan 3} [:table ["Opel" "XXX" "1972"]]]]]
    ]`